# generating a column based on the values in another column in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

The following is a subset of a data frame:

```
 drug_id    WD
lexapro.1   flu-like symptoms
lexapro.1   dizziness
lexapro.1   headache
lexapro.14  Dizziness
lexapro.14  headaches
lexapro.23  extremely difficult 
lexapro.32  cry at anything
lexapro.32  Anxiety
```

I need to generate a column `id` based on the values in `drug_id` as follows:

```
id    drug_id        WD
1       lexapro.1   flu-like symptoms
1       lexapro.1   dizziness
1       lexapro.1   headache 
2       lexapro.14  Dizziness
2       lexapro.14  headaches
3       lexapro.23   extremely difficult 
4       lexapro.32  cry at anything
4       lexapro.32  Anxiety
```

I think I need to group them based on drug_id and then generate id based on the size of each group. But I do not know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shift+cumsum pattern mentioned by Boud is good, just make sure to sort by `drug_id` first. So something like,

```
df = df.sort_values('drug_id')
df['id'] = (df['drug_id'] != df['drug_id'].shift()).cumsum()
```

A different approach that does not involve sorting your dataframe would be to map a number to each unique `drug_id`.

```
uid = df['drug_id'].unique() 
id_map = dict((x, y) for x, y in zip(uid, range(1, len(uid)+1))) 
df['id'] = df['drug_id'].map(id_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shift+cumsum pattern:

```
(df.drug_id!=df.drug_id.shift()).cumsum()
Out[5]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
7    4
Name: drug_id, dtype: int32
```

Comment: thank you, there is the following error: "Series lengths must match to compare", Do you know what is the reason ?

Comment: Yes. This is my code: df['id'] = (df.drug_id!=df.drug_id.shift()).cumsum()